# Is there a symbol used to say "subject to"?

Tags: optimization, notation

Long story short: I am writing notes which happen to use the expression *"subject to"* a lot. I would like to keep this shortened by using a symbol to represent the same, but have been unable to find one.

Context: Mostly, optimisation problems where:
$$
\min \mathbf{J} \quad \text{subject to} \; f
$$

Where $f$ - constraint; $\mathbf{J}$ - cost function

Is there a symbol to represent this?

If more context is needed, I can provide more actual examples.

Comment: A colon is used for such that, if that helps. e.g. $\left\{ x\in \mathbb{R}:x<4 \right\}$

Comment: @Arthur This might not apply. $\min \mathbf{J}(x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}}$ subject to $f(x) \leq 0$ - In this case, the contraint should not be a subscript to $\mathbf{J}$? 

A quote common abbreviation is 's.t.', for 'such that' / ' subject to':

\begin{align}
\min \mathbf{J}(x)_{x \in \mathbb{R}} & \text{ s.t. } f(x) \leq 0. 
\end{align}

Comment: $\min J(x_1,\ldots,x_n) : h(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \leqslant c$ or some such.

Comment: Abbreviations may work when lecturing on a board but in written notes it's much clearer to spell it out.

Comment: Thank you, all, for your input.
@lhf Quite right, I was confused when I first saw it as $s.t.$, but these notes are for personal use; I would use any-old notation, but do prefer to use something correct - if there is.

Comment: +1 for s.t.  In this use, s.t. can stand for either "subject to" or "such that", which fortunately are essentially synonymous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen two purely notational ways to do this (although I'm sure there are more):
$$
\min_{f(x)=0}\mathbf J(x)\\
\min \{\mathbf J(x)\mid f(x)=0\}
$$
Which one you like best is up to you.

Comment: Thank you, I suppose I am most likely to go with the second, as `min` often has subsets for `J`:
$$
\underset{u_1 , u_2}{\min} \, \mathbf{J}(u_1, u_2) = u_1 + u_2 \mid f(\underline{u}) = u_1 + 3u_2 - C = 0
$$